# Comparing a list of strings, one element at a time, against all elements in another list of strings

Tags: python, sql-server-2017

I have a dataset containing an ID, NamesA and NamesB.

I was initially asked to compare NamesA against NamesB for each row and produced the code shown. This gave me the required results (except for writing to csv instead of back into SQL).

I have now been asked to compare each element in NamesA against all elements of NamesB and return IDs in a new column for matches and similar strings.

I have tried to Google this, searching many different stackoverflow questions but have been unable to find/apply the right answer to my problem (due to my inexperience with Python and programming languages in general).

I am finding it difficult knowing how to approach this problem, attempting to use for loops but failing miserably!

The source data is in SQL server, where my colleague has been unable to perform this task. I have started to learn Python but have had limited success (again due to my inexperience).

```py
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
import jellyfish

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver=driver;"
                        "Server=server;"
                        "Database=db;"
                        "uid=user;pwd=password")

df = pd.read_sql_query('select top 100 [ID],[NamesA],[NamesB] from [table]', cnxn)

def similar(a, b):
    similarity = jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(str(a),str(b))
    return similarity

df['Similarity'] = df.apply(lambda z: similar(z['NamesA'],z['NamesB']), axis = 1)

df.to_csv("path.csv")
```

Using jellyfish gives a figure usable for this task but I've only been able to utilise this for an individual comparison.

Ideally, I am looking to produce something similar to this, where ratings of a 0 assign the ID to the MatchedIDs column and anything say between 1 - 5 would assign the ID to the SimilarIDs column.

```
¦ID ¦NamesA             ¦NamesB         ¦MatchedIDs ¦SimilarIDs
¦1  ¦Carly Thornton     ¦Ayla Vaughn    ¦2          ¦3, 4
¦2  ¦Falak Major        ¦Carly Thornton ¦null       ¦4
¦3  ¦Falak Vaughn       ¦Carly Major    ¦null       ¦1, 4
¦4  ¦Ayla Waller        ¦Falak Thornton ¦null       ¦1
```

Update - I think I've managed to apply the function using nested for loops but am still unable to return the IDs as desired. This method also appears to be quite slow testing with around 1/60th of the total data.

```py
for i in df["NamesA"]:
    for e in df["NamesB"]:
        if similar(i,e) < 5:
            print(i,e)
```

Comment: Please always specify the *version* of SQL Server you are using. Answers can differ because new, better features of the language have been added in newer versions